# Empty rows when added

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to create an XML save/load application. I'm using a `DataTable`, but when I use the code `DT.Rows.Add(txtName.text, etc...)` the rows created are empty. Here's my code:

```
Module SaveOrders
Sub Save(ByRef DT As DataTable)
    Dim M As New Main
    Dim ID As String = M.txtOrderID.Text
    DT.TableName = "Ordini"
    DT.Columns.Add("ID ordine")
    DT.Columns.Add("Descrizione")
    DT.Columns.Add("Prezzo")
    DT.Columns.Add("Compratore")
    DT.Columns.Add("Q.tà")
    DT.Rows.Add(ID, M.txtDescription.Text, M.txtPrice.Text, M.txtCustomer.Text, M.txtQuantity.Text)
    DT.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\order_" & ID + ".xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Why pass the `DataTable` by reference and then set properties of it as well as adding new columns and data to it, doesn't make any sense at all... Also you are not creating a new row object for exaple: `Dim dr As DataRow = DT.NewRow() ` Then you set the columns values for example: `dr("ID ordine") = "12"`. There are more than a few ways to do this, but it seems this is a debugging issue...

Comment: Additionally, whatever `Main` is, you just created a new one so everything there should be blank.  Nor is it clear why this is in a module if it is so reliant on a `Main` form (?).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]